# Responsiveslides just not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm using Responsive slides and I have gone according to the instructions on their site http://responsiveslides.com/ but it only shows my first image and does not slide...I have checked everything I can see but somehow it just doesn't work...I have uploaded it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q421n8xo/ and hope that someone will give me their valuable advice :) thanks! Oh and I think the dropdown menu is blocked by the images, is there a way to put it in front? Thanks again!

Okay major(?) breakthrough: I found out the responsiveSlides file I downloaded was incorrect...I got it working on jsfiddle...Kinda weird on my computer. Will try further.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hire a Bach</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
                auto: false,
                pager: true,
                speed: 500,
                maxwidth: 540
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class = "active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="hvar.html" class="dropbtn">Hvar</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                    <a href="activities.html">Activities</a>
                    <a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="rslides">
        <li><img src="images/bach1.jpg" alt="Bach1"></li>
        <li><img src="images/bach2.jpg" alt="Bach2"></li>
        <li><img src="images/bach3.jpg" alt="Bach3"></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>This old stone batch has the sea at its front door - built five meters from the sea it can't get closer to the clear azure Adriatic water. It is located in peaceful Jagodna bay, part of one of the most beautiful islands in the Adriatic. The house is surrounded by the beautiful Mediterranean bush full or aromatic rosemary and manuka. It is only five km from the famous medieval town of Hvar.</p>
    <p>Originally built as a family fishing batch, it has contained its character over the years. The house is made up of two separate apartments, each with two bedrooms and a terrace facing the sea. Each apartment can accommodate four people. </p>
    <p>This house can be rented as a whole or each apartment maybe separated rented. Kids and pets welcome.</p>
    <h2>Facilities</h2>
    <p>Fireplace, outdoor barbecue, showers  (indoor and outdoor) , Internet (WiFi), mobile coverage Vodafone, Sky TV, boat mooring , fridge, oven, linen provided.</p>
    <h2>Availability</h2>
    <p>Two European summer months: July and August</p>
    <div class="overflow">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Price per night</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Upper floor Apartment</td>
            <td><b>$120</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Basement Apartment</td>
            <td><b>$110</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Whole house</td>
            <td><b>$210</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <a target="_blank" title="Find us on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/PLACEHOLDER"><img alt="Find us on Facebook" src="images/facebookicon.png" border=0></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="Find us on Youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/PLACEHOLDER"><img alt="Find us on Youtube" src="images/youtubeicon.png" border=0></a>
</footer>
```

```
.active {
    background-color: grey;
}


table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #f6f1be;
}

.overflow {
    overflow-x:auto;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
}

nav li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

nav li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

nav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

nav .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
```

}

```
.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Your shorthand ready function must not have a dollar in front of it: (function($){    instead of   $(function($){      Check your console for errors (f12 and tab console in chrome)

Comment: I've tried using (function($) {
                $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
                    speed: 1000;
                    maxwidth: 800;
                });
but it does not work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't added the correct dependencies, I created a fork of you jsfiddle and its working https://jsfiddle.net/tphgwkhh/5/

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

Add jquery before the responsiveslides.min.js and it should be fine.
 For your second question add following css to your css file

```
 .dropdown-content{
    z-index:9999; 
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got the dropdown menu working, thanks! However, for the dependencies...I don't understand what's wrong @_@ as far as I can see I have exactly what's there i.e.
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

Comment: The order in my head currently is title-css-jqery-responsiveslides-script

Comment: I found my problem thanks to you! I never checked the script I downloaded, and I must have downloaded the wrong thing! Thank you heaps! It looks so great when working :3 note for anyone who downloads plugins online: check you downloaded it correctly, I'm serious. And jsfiddle.net helped me HEAPS while trying to find the problem as it at least tells you whether the problem is your HTML, CSS, or JS.

Comment: I am glad your issue is resolved, please accept the answer. Thanks